# How to show the latest data with range of date filter?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a view published in tableau server, which imports new data every day. This view has a range of date filter so the users can see the data of the dates they specify.
The problem is, the tableau server shows only the data range I specified when I published the view and the users have to slide the filter bar by themselves to see the latest data every time. For example, if I publish the view today, the view will keep showing the data until today even a month later.
Are there any ways to show the latest data automatically but keep using range of date filter?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the solution here: [How to put a filter to show latest two dates in Tableau?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880457/how-to-put-a-filter-to-show-latest-two-dates-in-tableau)

Been struggling for ages with this issue, and the above solution is simple and really elegant.

Answer (score 0):

usually it is an either/or option for your filtering

have you tried using Last() ?

Is your data broken up by days or do you have an example workbook you could share or Tableau Public?